# How to create call hierarchy graph in intellij idea professional for scala project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, optimization

Hello I'm trying to analyze some spaghetti-like code. I'm working in intellij idea professional, scala project.
My instruments:

1. Find usages
2. Call hierarchy
3. https://app.diagrams.net/
   It requires a lot of clicking copy-pasting. Is there a way to do it automatically? May be there are a good practices?

What I want to get:

1. See who calls method and whom this method calls with input parameters (variables).
2. Where do variables come? Like config file / calculated / hard-coded / instance of a class.
3. Imports of global variables

Comment: It isn't clear to me what do you want to achieve. Description is missing any question and only the title suggest that you want to do somehow make Intellij generate graph... but how exactly? For any non-trivial project visualizing all usages as graphs would easily be to cluttered to be able to read anything.

Comment: I want to understand code dependencies, where variables are created, hierarchy call. I understand that graph can be cluttered, that's why I'm asking for best practice.

Comment: In every project that I worked with, I could get away with just [keyboards shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html): "Go to definition", "Find usages", "Search everywhere". I sometimes requires several jumps but I usually find what I am looking for.

Comment: I don't think there's any one tool that can do all this in the way you want.